Origin of tangent cone
Salmon uses the properties of the branch curve of a cubic surface to show that the number of nodes (“double points”) of a singular cubic surface is limited. He indicates that

we have seen that the tangent cone necessarily has a certain number
of double and cuspidal edges, and since every double point on the
surface adds a double edge to the tangent cone, there cannot be more double points than will make up the total number of double edges of
the tangent cone to the maximum number which such a cone can have. (Ibid., p. 379)

The above paragraph is an excerpt from pages 54-55 of the book Duality in 19th and 20th century mathematical thinking.
Following the comment from the person who commented on my question, I did some more research on tangent cones and found the following book, which helped me learn more about tangent cones. So I guess the tangent cone was invented by Salmon and Plucker. Is this idea correct?
Edit: I found paper, A PLURALITY OF (NON)VISUALIZATIONS: BRANCH POINTS
AND BRANCH CURVES AT THE TURN OF THE 19TH CENTURY If you see this paper's 151 page, you can see this following paragraph:

Salmon calls this collection of all
lines tangent to the surface the “tangent cone” [Salmon 1862, p. 190],
and notes

I think that Salmon is creator of tangent cone concept.

The point of Dolecki and Greco's articles is that, according to them, Peano has priority over a series of concepts and theorems that are usually considered to belong to the 1920s, 1930s, or even later; therefore, if one must doubt their work, the most natural question, in my opinion, would be "are we sure that Peano's exposition is exactly the same, or is it a simpler or less precise version?" rather than "wasn't there someone even before Peano?"

The term tangent cone (and equivalent) was used before Salmon numerous times. Compare for example:
A. M. Legendre (1788) Mémoire sur les Intégrales doubles. In Mémoires de la Classe des sciences, mathématiques et physiques de l'Institut national de France (1791). pp. 454-486, mention of "cone tangent" p. 473.
The term seems to have been in fairly common use through the early 19th century in different languages (cone tangent (French), tangent cone (English), Tangentenkegel or Berührungskegel (German)).
Examples: Crozet (1831), Hamilton (1833), Wolff (1835), Cayley (1846). Particularly remarkable in this list are Crozet and Wolff as they were texts written for use in cadet training in a military academy, and trade school use of a descriptive geometry course, respectively. This suggests that it was a fairly basic term and concept appropriate for non-expert exposition at the time. This is explainable by the fact the there are very easy to conceive elementary examples:

(from Strubecker, K. (1958). Vorlesungen über darstellende Geometrie. Vanderhoeck & Ruprecht. p. 179)
The notion of tangency is old (compare Coolidge 1951), and it is certainly possible that the concept of a tangent cone is quite ancient as well. Certainly post hoc even early tangency constructions to the circle can be viewed as tangent cones. I am not aware if attempts have been made to pin-point who might have crystalized it as a concept, though I would guess it predates Legendre.

Hello, thank you very much for your answer. It cleared up my doubts.
